# sql looking for pattern

Tags: sql

I have a string similar to this `'MSH|^~\&|STF_ALL_LAB_IN_C...`

I'm trying to find some sql that will bring back all messages that contain

```
MSH|^~\&|(any 3 characters)_(anything after the underscore).
```

Tried something like this

```
WHERE TransText LIKE 'MSH|^~\&|%_%_%_'
```

But that doesn't seem to require the underscore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

> MSH|^~&|(any 3 characters)_(anything after the underscore).

The pattern would be:

```
where TransText like 'MSH|^~\&|___\_%'
```

In some databases, the backslash would need to be escaped, so that would be:

```
where TransText like 'MSH|^~\\&|___\_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

`_` is a special character in a `LIKE` clause. It matches any *one* character, where `%` matches any series of 0 or more characters.

You need to escape it, using `\_`.